# Multi-language website and .js files

Tags: php, javascript, multilingual

My website is multi-language. I'm using php files to define my words / sentences in several languages.

My problem is that my website contains .js files, in which i can't write php code.

What I am suppose to do when I need to make an alert containing some sentence or some word in my .js file ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [what are the different approaches to multilingual javascript applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664581/what-are-the-different-approaches-to-multilingual-javascript-applications)

Comment: Bad idea: server all your JS files from a PHP file that outputs with language spec. Maybe better idea: update your JS files to use a global array called LANG and use PHP to populate the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You COULD have your js utilize a json obj or an array of strings...

PHP could then create these and write the json or array in the head section on page load..

Comment: Thanks, will probably use json, I wondered if there was something simpler but obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

you can save you JS files as FILENAME.js.php... Within them you can run some Magic.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax and JSON is the best way to do this. But you can actually make put PHP is javascript files, with a little htaccess manipulation.